# How to refactor/rename tables, fields and values in a large database quickly?

Tags: mysql, refactoring

I have a MySQL database that has more than 100 tables with a lot of fields and setting values. We are updating our codes and database structure every few days. What is the quickest/easiest way to refactor/rename our database tables, fields, values and etc?

Comment: Luckily, you will never need to do this.

Comment: Do you have any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby on Rails is good at this http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html
PHP also has a variety of Active Record implementations that might help.
Otherwise I'd just create SQL scripts and commit them to source control along with the code changes.